# Swift: How to access a label in a custom cell within a certain tableView section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UILabel` called `CellLabel`. I want to be able to access this label at a certain `tableView section` e.g. section 3 and provide it a string to display without the use of an array and `arrayName[indexPath.section]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` override of a `TableView`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCustomCellRegisterName") as YourCustomCell
    if(indexPath.section == 3){
       cell.CellLabel.text = "foo"
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does that work if the cells are in section instead of rows? e.g. 5 sections with 1 cell in each section

Comment: @R.Ham i've updated my answer, you can change each section name like that

Comment: Will that be able to change the cellLabel.text? or just the header name?

Comment: @R.Ham now it is what you are looking for

Comment: happy swift coding!